# Import json behind a custom google map into R

Tags: r, json, google-maps-api-3, geojson, r-sf

I'd like to import the shapefile behind this google map into R :
https://motoneiges.ca/magazines/motoneiges/cartes/carte.jsp

I have found this JSON, which appears to be the source behind it:
https://mca.viaexplora.com/db/graphSentiersSS.json

I have read it into R using jsonlite::fromJSON, but everything appears encoded, and I am not sure what to to with it.

```
test <- fromJSON("graphSentiersSS.json")
str(test)
List of 7
 $ : int 2
 $ : chr "I2loB2m4CI| __truncated__
 $ : chr "BdItBqAI"| __truncated__
 $ : chr [1:4] "DI66tcrI137Bz"| __truncated__ 
               "DB74slI14sB16__truncated__
               "DB5wGFGHHFHGHHFHGFHACGFHHGHHHHHGJAFAFG"| __truncated__ 
               "DIzFGFACHGGFGFHFGHCA"| __truncated__
 $ :List of 14
 $ :List of 200
  .. [list output truncated]
 $ : num 3e-06
```

Applyinh "googlePolylines::decode()" to  parts of it "kinda worked" because it returned something, but all the lat/lons were way off near 0 degree lat 0 degree lon

```
test2 <- googlePolylines::decode(test[[2]])
> test2
[[1]]
            lat           lon
1    0.00005000 -1.000000e-04
2   -0.01794000 -2.000000e-04
3   -0.01451000 -1.800000e-04
4   -0.01446000 -2.900000e-04
5    0.00372000 -4.000000e-04
6    0.05790000  1.900000e-04
7    0.05976000  1.500000e-04
8    0.05981000  5.000000e-05
...
```

and this is where I gave up.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your problem, but maybe this site helps you.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Comment: interesting! the fact that they  only encode the difference with the previous point makes sense with the fact that I have mostly points around latitude = 0 and longitude =0.  But I would expect a first point around where this map is centered.